# How remove last symbols in string without left and substring?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove the last characters from a string, while functions such as left and substring cannot be used. What function can this be done? You can only use functions that remove characters to the right.

```
SELECT col
FROM table
WHERE col = LEFT('EXAMPLE', 1);
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: If `left` and `substring` are prohibited, which string functions can you use? `right`, `replace` can you?

Comment: You can only use functions that remove characters to the right.

Comment: Why can't you use a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`regexp_replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).  For instance, to return the string without the last five characters:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '.{5}$', '')
```

This gives you lots and lots of flexibility on the number of characters and the type of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT INSERT(col,LENGTH(col),1,'')
```